# Access sequence from another schema in JPA

Tags: java, database, jpa

I have the "master_seq" defined in 2 schemes. I have a table in schema_2 say table_2. Schema_1 has been provided insert grant on table_2 and its master_seq. The problem is, I am trying to insert a record in table_2 from schema_1 (From the spring boot app I am running) and it is using schema_1's master_seq whereas I want it should use schema_2's master_seq.

In short, I want to use master_seq of the schema where the table is.

Below is the code sample:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="MASTER_SEQ")


@SequenceGenerator(name="MASTER_SEQ",sequenceName="MASTER_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
            public Long getId() {
                return id;
            }
```

Do I need to use another schema name in code somehow? But schema name keeps on changing as per the different environment.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try accessing the sequence by appending the schema name to sequence name:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="MASTER_SEQ",sequenceName="schema_2.MASTER_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
```